# How to see imported plugins in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, slack

I'm trying to notify my Slack when a SonarQube analysis has been processed and for that I saw a plugin: https://github.com/astrebel/sonar-slack-notifier-plugin

I followed all the step but I didn't see the slack hook setting in my administration/general view.

Comment: The title seems not to match your question. I would suggest `How to configure the Sonar Slack Notifier plugin?`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your version of SonarQube, but that plugin's README clearly states that it is no longer maintained, and implies that it's not compatible above SonarQube 5.4.

Assuming you have a more recent version than that, you should look at the [built-in webhooks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks), which will POST notifications once analysis reports have been integrated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response !

Comment: @Fosfor if it helped you, you might Accept it... :-)